# Jquery - Submit a form with button

Tags: jquery, html, button, submit

I have this form:

```
<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="/" name="sform">
    <div class="search-box">
        <input type="text" name="s" class="prac-area-search" />

        <input id="sbutton" type="button" />

    </div>
    <div class="search-hidden-btn"><input type="submit" id="ssubmit" class="search-submit screen-reader-text" value="Search"></div>

</form>
```

. The submit button is hidden, I would like to submit the the form while clicking the `#sbutton` button is clicked.
For some reason the form is not submitted when i click the button  `#sbutton`

This is the jquery code I tried:

```
<script>
$('#sbutton').click(function(){
  $('form[name=sform]').submit();
});
</script>
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: your code works, where is the problem?

Comment: Did you include the jquery library, first of all? :\

Comment: i want the form to be submitted when i click the  `#sbutton` button. the jquery is included. i dont understand why it dosent work

Comment: this is the link to the site http://sparke.co.il/  i am talking about the search bar at the top of the screen

Comment: @DavSev Why the action is just a slash?

Comment: If we open your site - we see `TypeError: $ is not a function $(document).ready(function(){`

Comment: for some reason your jquery is not loaded it says $ is not defined in Firefox

Answer (score 1):

I understand your problem, before you create Handler on DOM element with jquery you need to wait DOM is ready.

Try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#sbutton').click(function(){
          $('form[name=sform]').submit();
        });
});
```

**UPDATE**

in Wordpress jQuery.noConflict() is called on the jQuery file it includes (scroll to the bottom of the file it's including for jQuery to see this), which means $ doesn't work, but jQuery does.

Comment: thank you, tried it. for some reason it dosent work...  this is the link to the site sparke.co.il i am talking about the search bar at the top of the screen

Comment: replace $ with jQuery :)